# Calling parsley.js method 'addError' on the instance directly

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsley.js, parsley

I have the following HTML source (generated by Django template engine):

```
<input class="form-control input-sm" id="id_kpp" maxlength="45" name="kpp" pattern="^\d{12}$|^\d{10}$" required="" type="text" data-parsley-group="block-0">
```

When I try to apply this code to the element:

```
var elem = $('#id_kpp').parsley();
var error_name = 'multiple_inn_kpp';
elem.removeError(error_name);
window.ParsleyUI.addError(elem, error_name, 'My custom error msg');
```

..I get a warning in Google Chrome stating that

> Accessing ParsleyUI is deprecated. Call 'addError' on the instance
>   directly. Please comment in issue 1073 as to your need to call this
>   method.

I tried to rewrite the removeError-part the following way and it worked for me.

```
 elem.removeError(error_name);
```

But if I try to rewrite addError-part in the similar way:

```
elem.addError(error_name, 'My custom error msg');
```

I get error message in the Browser:

> parsley.js:1000 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of
>   undefined

The [doc](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/#psly-ui-for-field) is very sketchy on using addError method. Any ideas ?

Comment: Working example: `$("[pac_input]").parsley().addError("myError", { message: "missing number" });`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`elem.addError(error_name, {message: 'My custom error msg'});`

I've added colons in the doc, hoping that it will be more clear now.